# Problemas al adjuntar archivo cuando envío correo con función mail() +PHP +HTML

Tags: php, html, mail

¡Holaa!

Estoy intentando enviar un correo adjuntando un archivo pero no hay manera.

Mi código HTML es el siguiente:

```
<?php
 
  $recipient_email = 'prueba@prueba.com';
  $subject = "Mensaje de prueba";
  $message = "Hola, esto es una prueba";

  if (isset($_FILES['csv'])) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
    $type = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];
    $error = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];

    $total = count($_FILES['csv']['name']);

    for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
      $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'][$i];

      $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
      $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
      $headers .= "From:" . "doc@gestio.aliance-brother.com";

      $mensaje .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
      $mensaje .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
      $mensaje .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
      $mensaje .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\r\n\r\n";  
      $mensaje .= $encoded_content;

      mail($recipient_email, $subject, $mensaje, $headers);
      
    }

    header('Location: https://' . $servidor . '/home.php');

}
```

Sintáxicamente parece estar correcto, puesto que no peta por ningún lado, el problema es que no me llega ningún correo.

¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Si envias el correo sin adjuntos se envia correctamente?

Comment: no, no se realiza el envío .